# Асинхронная очередь для бота в телеграм

Tags: python, очередь, asyncio, aiogram

У меня в боте есть кнопка "Подтвердить заказ" и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь нажимает на эту кнопку, открывалась очередь из всех отправленных заказов со статусом 0 и проверяла нет ли заказов со статусом 1 (0 - в ожидании, 1 - в процессе, 2 - завершен), потом если заказов в процессе нет, то брала бы первый отправленный заказ и отправляла его на проверку.
Мне нужно, чтобы пока бот все это делал, я мог писать ему другие сообщения и он бы мне на них отвечал.
Направьте меня, пожалуйста, на нужные источники если вы знаете, а то я уже весь интернет перерыл и не смог найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать модуль `queue`

Например:

```
from queue import Queue
def q(zakazi):
    q=Queue()
    for i in zakazi:
        q.put(i)
    return q
```

Возвращает очередь со списком заданий.Создайте 3 таких очереди и поочередно проверяйте. (или можно добавить по потоку,чтобы в них проверялась только одна конкретная очередь)
Подробнее про модуль [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Comment: есть асинхронная очередь в асинкио. а эта зависнет

Comment: Возможно это костыль,но с threading работает замечательно и не виснет.

Comment: Но как же асинкио?)